# can Google geocode NUTS area codes?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-fusion-tables

I tried to geocode NUTS codes in Google Fusion Tables (using some Maps API in the background), but despite receiving no error messages or warning, it did not recognize these spatial units. [NUTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclature_of_Territorial_Units_for_Statistics) area codes are fairly standard, even official in Europe, with [publicly available](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/popups/references/administrative_units_statistical_units_1) shapefiles. Can one easily geolocate using only these codes?

E.g. NUTS codes are in column #7 of [my public table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1QAF70Jwy-KdSd5K-NyrGCzWyxhJF1EbCnszT18o#rows%3aid=1) (on all Hungarian public procurement contracts 2009-2012).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import shapefiles into FusionTables using [shpescape.com/ft](http://www.shpescape.com/ft/).

Importing nuts_2010_03m_sh_data_nuts_rg_03m_2010.shp into FusionTables gives me this:

[map](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col0+from+1otpl2-2zx7ZiuDTufuiN00OK13eAVfPfUKdlRMY+where+col3+contains+ignoring+case+%27HU%27&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=47.16085325054245&lng=19.522361610375015&t=1&z=6&l=col0&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=KML)

[image: screenshot of map]

If I merge that on the NUTS "id", I get this:

[map](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col0%3E%3E1+from+1M1K5cBRsnXW4MAZP-ZIlk5qx8FdriMYInrz9MIY+where+col6%3E%3E0+contains+ignoring+case+%27HU%27&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=46.66742488856679&lng=18.989524696312497&t=1&z=6&l=col0%3E%3E1&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=GEOCODABLE)

[image]